# Is there a way to create a "custom" loop or control structure in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, control-structure

I'm creating a very large page that at various parts needs to loop through a data array like this:

```
$processed = array();
foreach( $data as $program )
{
    if( $program['f_enabled'] == 'N' ) continue;
    $pid = $program['f_programId'];
    if( !array_key_exists($pid, $processed) )
    {
        /**
         *  Do things with $pid and $program['f_foobar'], including
         *  ?>
         *      <span>HTML with <?=$inlined_vars?></span>
         *  <?php
         */
        $processed[] = $pid;
    }
}
```

This is reminiscent to me of the WordPress Loop. I know I can compact all the loops into one, storing HTML output in variables and piecing them together at the end, but I strongly desire for code to appear in alignment with the HTML that will surround it.

How can I factor out everything on the outside? Even if it's as hacky as:

```
MY_HORRIFYING_MACRO
{
        /**
         *  Do things with $pid and $program['f_foobar'], including
         *  ?>
         *      <span>HTML with <?=$inlined_vars?></span>
         *  <?php
         */
}
```

I'm not concerned about correctness here—I just need this demo to work, and for the code to be readable in a presentation top-to-bottom with a synchronized sense of what else is on the page. Preferably PHP 5.3-compatible—not positive the demo server will be running PHP 5.4+—but if a solution exists using PHP 5.4+ constructs, please share anyway. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit a great deal from using a modern templating language like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: Twig looks awesome. Reminds me of Angular, but seems more specifically geared toward templating. Unfortunately I lack the time / there's some uncertainty about the presentation platform...

Comment: It should take you all of 15 minutes to get up and running with Twig. It's syntax is very simple and the documentation is excellent. You will spend more time hacking away at the monster that is PHP+HTML.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this, even using some convoluted method like a function with a heredoc function body? (I would guess the server would raise security errors, however...)

Comment: You can keep looking for convoluted and outdated ways to solve your problem or you can take the opportunity to learn something that will advance your skills tremendously.

Comment: @Marty - I'll be installing this on a shared hosting environment with no shell access...

Comment: You don't need shell access - it's a simple PHP package :-)

Comment: @Marty - Yes... but I'm a full-time C++ dev who just happens to be doing an odd job; I kind of want to be done with it and never touch PHP again. Twig looks great, but conceptually I already get how it would work, it's not rocket science, so I'm not sure what I'd gain by it. That said, if you know how I can get it running on a shared hosting environment, I'll install it right away.

Comment: @Marty - Ah, I must have misread the documentation. I saw git, pear, C extensions, and gave up. I see the tarball option now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I wanted by using callbacks.

First, define the wrapper ("macro") function, like so:

```
function my_macro($data, $fn)
{
    foreach( $data as $program )
    {
        if( $program['f_enabled'] == 'N' ) continue;
        $pid = $program['f_programId'];
        if( !array_key_exists($pid, $processed) )
        {
            call_user_func($fn, $program, $pid);
        }
    }
}
```

So in the above, I'm passing down `$program` and `$pid` to a not-yet-defined callback function, as these two variables are always needed, and needed frequently.

To actually use this construct, one would simply do this:

```
my_macro(function($program, $pid)
{
    /**
     *  Do things here, including
     *  ?>
     *      <span>HTML with <?=$pid?> and <?=$program['title']?></span>
     *  <?php
     */
});
```

And you can disperse this wherever you like in your page. You can of course have as many frequently-used variables as you like in addition to `$program` and `$pid`.

I still recommend reading @Marty's advice in the question's comments for a proper, non-hacky approach. But yeah, that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a new control structure (as you would in Ruby), you can do something with more boilerplate but more idiomatically PHP like this:

```
$processed = array();
function preloop($program) {
    if( $program['f_enabled'] == 'N' ) return true;
    $pid = $program['f_programId'];
    if( !array_key_exists($pid, $processed) )
    {
        $processed[] = $pid;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
foreach( $data as $program ) {
    if (preloop($program))
        continue;

    // do things with program
}
// somewhere else
foreach( $data as $program ) {
    if (preloop($program))
        continue;

    // do things with program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like that in `PHP`, but for the processing of datas to be shown in `HTML` use something like `Twig` or similar.